# svgIcon doesn't work, url throws 404

Tags: lightning-aura-components, svg-icon

I am new to SForce lightning, i have added svgIcon component as described by the link: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/

But when i try:

```
<c:svgIcon svgPath="/resource/slds214/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#user" category="standard" size="large" name="user" />
```

It does not display icon??? on developer console it displays as 404 error??

Aren't following icons are available for development?
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new, preferred method is to use [lightning:icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_icon.htm) or [lightning:buttonIcon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_buttonIcon.htm). If you insist on using `svgIcon`, make sure you have the right resource path. Static resources are available in Lightning, but you have to make sure you have the path just right. Most likely, you meant to write: `/resource/slds214/icons/standard-sprites/svg/symbols.svg#user` instead, but you'll want to check the zip file to confirm this.

Comment: so does these components are still valid?? https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/   , all of these are using tag *svg*

Comment: @dev.sforce svgIcon still works, I have it scattered through my projects, but I've been converting them to lightning:icon as appropriate, with the hope of one day removing the static resource entirely.

Comment: what do i need to get svgIcon working with following components? https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/

Comment: @dev.sforce Replace the entire svg structure with the relevant lightning:icon, like this: `<lightning:icon iconName="utility:search" />`, or use `svgIcon` where the `use xlink:href` is moved up to the `svgPath` attribute of the `svgIcon`. I strongly recommend the former solution, as svgIcon was only meant to be a crutch until it wasn't needed.